# Performance and scalability to have one data structure or splitting data structures in MongoDB

Tags: database, mongodb, database-design, database-performance

Is there a performance difference if you have an array within a data set (`tags`) like this:

images cluster:

```
{
  _id: 'imageID1',
  title: 'some title name',
  tags: ['cool', 'banana', 'animal']
},
{
  _id: 'imageID2',
  title: 'some other title name',
  tags: ['funny', 'creative', 'animal']
}
```

vs separating the array into different clusters? (I'm using mongodb as my database)

images cluster:

```
{
  _id: 'imageID1',
  title: 'some title name',
  tagsId: 'imageID1tags'
},
{
  _id: 'imageID2',
  title: 'some other title name',
  tagsId: 'imageID2tags'
}
```

Tags cluster:

```
{
  _id: '1',
  imagesId: 'imageID1',
  tag: 'cool'
},
{
  _id: '2',
  imagesId: 'imageID1',
  tag: 'banana'
},
{
  _id: '3',
  imagesId: 'imageID1',
  tag: 'animal'
},
{
  _id: '4',
  imagesId: 'imageID2',
  tag: 'funny'
},
{
  _id: '5',
  imagesId: 'imageID2',
  tag: 'creative'
},
{
  _id: '6',
  imagesId: 'imageID2',
  tag: 'animal'
},
```

Just side note: You can see (for example purposees), I have 2 animal data, where 1 of them belongs to `imageID1` and another `imageID2`. This cluster will have endless amounts of tags, where it can be duplicate names, unique to its `imagesId`.

So does it make sense to just simplify it (for scalability and performance considerations) and have it within the images cluster (just 1 data cluster), or spread it out (having 2 data clusters)? I want to eventually do a search on the tags, and then the images associated to the search tag will populate.

So if user searches `animal`, both of the images will show up.

Comment: How many _tags_ are likely to be for each _image_ entity?

Comment: It's better save them inside single collection if your top-level document doesn't exceed 16MB

Comment: @prasad_ hmmm indefinitely? Looking for long term application.

Comment: @Valijon ah okay, thanks! i'll probably do that then.

Comment: In general, if you have data in two collections (_not_ clusters), if you want to access data from both, it is a more work and it can affect performance. To understand how to design, one of the things you have to know ahead is what are the _most_ important queries you will be making with this data in your application.